# Saving colorindexed Tiff using LibTiff.net throws exception

Tags: c#, bitmap, libtiff, libtiff.net

I'm trying to save a colorindexed Bitmap to Tiff using Libtiff.net.
But it throws an OutOfRangeException:
[image: Exception]

The exception occurs if i set and indexed colormap:

```
       internal static bool SaveColorPalette(Bitmap source, Tiff destTiff, int bitsPerSample)
    {
        destTiff.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.PALETTE);
        var paletteSize = 1 << bitsPerSample;
        var palette = source.Palette.Entries;
        var reds = new short[paletteSize];
        var greens = new short[paletteSize];
        var blues = new short[paletteSize];
        for (var i = 0; i < palette.Length && i < paletteSize; ++i)
        {
            var color = palette[i];
            reds[i] = color.R;
            greens[i] = color.G;
            blues[i] = color.B;
        }

        destTiff.SetField(TiffTag.COLORMAP, reds, greens, blues);
        return true;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this?

Thanks.

Edit:
The exception occurs when i save the Tiff with

```
outputTiff.WriteDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution.

First you have to define

```
TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE
```

The **Tiff.SetField** function for **TiffTag.COLORMAP** use this to calculate the array length, instead of relying on C# length property.

See line 231 at
[TiffTagMethods](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/blob/master/LibTiff/TiffTagMethods.cs)